# How to turn off cheats in minecraft after creating the world with cheats enabled

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm creating a Minecraft map that I want players to not have permissions to use cheats so they cant use the setblock command and set blocks as air and break the map. Is there any way I can turn off cheats after creating the world with cheats on? (to get command blocks)

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use a NBT editor such as NBTEdit and somewhere in the tags, there should be a tag with cheats equaling "1." Change that to 0 and cheats will be disabled. The tag is near the hardcore tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this a easier way, create a world with no cheats and then open the world to LAN and enable cheats, this will activate cheats as long as the world is open with cheats. Then simply close the world and there will be no cheats enabled.

---

If you have a current world that was created with cheats then create a brand new world without cheats, then duplicate the previous world and use the `world.dat` folder to replace the brand new worlds `world.dat` folder and this will make it so there are no cheats, then use the trick listed above to enable cheats in the new world.