# How can I change the world spawn in a Minecraft BE Realm with no cheats and allow achievements?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-realms

I'm trying to start a Minecraft Realm with a modified worldspawn for a group of Bedrock version players. Otherwise, it's vanilla survival, and ideally would like players to be able to earn achievements in this SMP crew.

It doesn't seem worthwhile to enable cheats solely to make that one change and then turn them off for the server. I've looked into grabbing the dat files and making changes there, but Bedrock seems to keep that data in the log files. Honestly, I'm not very clear on the Bedrock version file format. Nor am I sure that uploading a world like that will work for Realms as I'm new to that too.

For those curious, the seed is https://www.chunkbase.com/apps/biome-finder#-34162643875163362 here with an amazing "heart-shaped" forest island as a starter area, surrounded by all sorts of different ocean types including a nearby monument, and great access to Giant Taiga, Jungle, Desert, Savanah, Mountains, Dark Forest, Swamp, and Flower Biomes, all within about 500 blocks. Killer seed. But the 0,-,0 coordinate is *just* barely off the tip of the heart island, so the game logic kicks spawn to far east instead of onto the island. Moving spawn to -32,82,32 is perfect. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: One answer that seemed relevant is here https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/283850/how-to-turn-off-cheats-in-minecraft-after-creating-the-world-with-cheats-enabled/328144 where they set up the world as needed, then create a fresh world and swap the .dat files. Again, i'm not sure how to do this with Bedrock.

Comment: You can answer and accept your own question by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this and figured I'd post the results in case someone else runs across this question.

You'll need an NBT editor to modify the tags (I was trying to do it with a text editor, and unfortunately the data is stored as binary so that's not a great way to do it.) There is the "Universal Minecraft Editor" available among others that is suitable for modifying bedrock files.

The level format is described [in the official thread](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bedrock_Edition_level_format).

Changing BOTH the SpawnX,Y,Z values and the LimitedWorldOriginX,Y,Z values to be -32,82,32 got this sorted.